# Debug ROS2 launch using gdb with launch-prefix

Tags: ros2, roslaunch, gdb

ROS2 version: humble

System: ubuntu 20.04

When I cross-compile and successfully build the ROS project, I copy the "install" directory to the development board and execute `source install/setup.bash` on the board.

I want to debug my CPP program using GDB, so I wrote the following "launch.py" file.

```py
def generate_launch_description():
    joint_model_share_path = get_package_share_directory("joint_model")
    params_file_path = os.path.join(joint_model_share_path, 'config/params.yaml')
    return LaunchDescription([
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='joint_model', executable='joint_model_node', output='screen',
            parameters=[{
                'params_file': params_file_path
            }],
            prefix=['gdb -ex start --args']
            ),
    ])
```

Since I'm logging in to the development board via SSH, I didn't use the commonly used "xterm" but directly used "gdb" as a prefix to avoid create new terminal windows.

However, after running the program, I see the following log information, and the program seems to get stuck and doesn't progress. I tried typing "continue", but it didn't work. Also, I'm pretty sure the program should log some information when it runs.

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/admin/.ros/log/2023-08-28-23-09-02-744048-ub20-384593
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [gdb-1]: process started with pid [384639]
[gdb-1] GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.2
[gdb-1] Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
[gdb-1] License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
[gdb-1] This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
[gdb-1] There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
[gdb-1] Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
[gdb-1] This GDB was configured as "aarch64-linux-gnu".
[gdb-1] Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
[gdb-1] For bug reporting instructions, please see:
[gdb-1] <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
[gdb-1] Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
[gdb-1]     <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
[gdb-1] 
[gdb-1] For help, type "help".
[gdb-1] Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
[gdb-1] Reading symbols from /home/admin/joint_model/install/joint_model/lib/joint_model/joint_model_node...
[gdb-1] Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x4b64: file /home/<username>/ws/build/joint_model/rclcpp_components/node_main_joint_model_node.cpp, line 27.
[gdb-1] Starting program: /home/admin/joint_model/install/joint_model/lib/joint_model/joint_model_node --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_1o9to7xt
[gdb-1] [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[gdb-1] Using host libthread_db library "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[gdb-1] [New Thread 0xffffbeb01920 (LWP 384726)]
[gdb-1] [New Thread 0xffffbe300920 (LWP 384727)]
[gdb-1] 
[gdb-1] Thread 1 "joint_model_nod" hit Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=4, 
[gdb-1]     argv=0xfffffffff058)
[gdb-1]     at /home/<username>/ws/build/joint_model/rclcpp_components/node_main_joint_model_node.cpp:27
[gdb-1] 27  /home/<username>/ws/build/joint_model/rclcpp_components/node_main_joint_model_node.cpp: No such file or directory.

continue
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[gdb-1] Quit
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT) again, ignoring...
[gdb-1] Quit
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT) again, ignoring...
[gdb-1] Quit
cat[ERROR] [gdb-1]: process[gdb-1] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
[INFO] [gdb-1]: sending signal 'SIGTERM' to process[gdb-1]
[gdb-1] Exception ignored in: <gdb._GdbOutputFile object at 0xffffb125d760>
[gdb-1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[gdb-1]   File "/usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/__init__.py", line 43, in flush
[gdb-1]     def flush(self):
[gdb-1] KeyboardInterrupt: 
[INFO] [gdb-1]: process has finished cleanly [pid 384639]
[gdb-1] (gdb) (gdb) (gdb) (gdb)
```

I waited for at least ten minutes before using Ctrl+C to forcibly terminate the program, so it's not because I terminated the program too early.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: It seems like it was running - were you expecting more logging output?

Comment: After I type the `continue` command, it doesn't logging anything though I wait for at least 10 minutes. I'm sure there will be some logging information, because without gdb, it does.